# Updating data while they are displayed and accessed in a TableView

Tags: iphone, database, multithreading, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with this.
First, I have a lot of data I display in a UITableView. These datas can be accessed by click (the index of the row permits to know which data to access).
Besides, I update and add data using a second thread. This second thread could change the data list.

The problem is that in some situation I can be accessing data (click on a cell), but it has been modified between the moment I load them in the UITableView and the moment I access them. It could lead the click to the wrong data or a deleted data, or a SegFault...

To prevent this, I make an immutable copy of the data when I load the UITableView, and the UITableView and cells only refer to the copy.

As I am a beginner, I was managing data using **XMLs and memory** (not CoreData or SQLLite). Now I plan to change this architecture to go for **SQLLite** (mainly for persistence).

I have two questions :

- Can I use SQLLite or a CoreData mechanic to generate a cached copy (a temporary table for example). Have I to do it manually (insert into desttable select * from sourcetable) or is there something made for the purpose I describe ?
- Do you think using **temporary tables** is a good mean to do what I want ?

Thanks for your answers and your help.

Karim

Comment: Your question covers several issues that I think you should try to de-couple, such as don't confuse a UITableView (a user-visible table) with a database table.  What is the nature of the background thread that is modifying the data?  Is it removing rows from the ui table or appending them?

Comment: In fact the second thread do not change the tableview. To make it simple : The table display a feed of news and the global news list of the app is filled by a second thread. Reload of tableview is done through user actions...

Comment: News from war : It works just great using Core Data and two threads filling two different contexts. Just keep in mind that second thread has to notify main thread of CD updates !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData uses a [`NSManagedObjectContext`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) which keeps track of all changes in memory until a method such as `save:`, `rollback`, or `reset` is called. In a separate thread you could create another `NSManagedObjectContext` that updates all of the data but does not save any data until certain synchronization criteria is met (ie. the user is no longer editing the table). Once all criteria is met you can save the `NSManagedObjectContext` and reload the table.

**Note:**

Background threads that use core data need to notify the main thread of changes.

[Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385)

Comment: This is it. 24H of mind twisting on guides and tutorials lead to the same conclusion : CoreData is made for that. Thanks for the hint !